# How to view the used space of a volume in OpenStack

Tags: openstack, disk-volume, openstack-nova

In OpenStack, is there a way to view the used space of a volume? In another words, what is the equivalent of the `virt-df <domain> --human` command in OpenStack `api`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `cinder` CLI or the OpenStack Dashboard (Horizon).

1. `cinder list`
2. `cinder show <volume-id>`
3. Look for the field `size` which shows the total volume size in GB.
4. Look for the field `os-vol-host-attr:host` that shows the host's name to which the volume is attached.
5. SSH into the host and `df -h <mount-point>`

Comment: Thanks. Is there also `api` to get the `used` space of the volume?

Comment: `GET /volumes/{volume_id}/stats`
`GET /os-volumes/{volume_id}/usage`

This will return a JSON object containing information about the volume usage, including the total number of reads and writes, the number of bytes read and written, and the last time the volume was accessed.

Comment: It returns null to me. would you please give me a link to its documentation?

Comment: https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/block-storage/

Comment: Sorry, the link you mentioned does not have the APIs you said before.